# Creating webpage in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, html

Recently i created an application in scheme/racket which ought to solve the art gallery problem. It takes input from user graphically and shows the user solution and procedure to find good approximation to minimum number of cameras.

Now i want to create a webpage where you can use the application online. So can i use my racket source code in webpage and if so how?
My source code : https://github.com/Naman-ntc/Art-Gallery-Problem (in case you want to have a look!)

Comment: I made my Thesis documentation with scribble. You might want to take a look at it https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/ (Yes, you can run evaluations of code using scribble, just like in the doc pages from racket!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "Continue: Web Applications in Racket" by Danny Yoo and Jay McCarthy.

http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/popl16/doc/continue/index.html